# (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a csv which I could import to my database without errors. When I tried to import it through python I receive this message :

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 4 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values.

I don't have any values null or even float in my csv as I said I imported without problems through sql task import.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\myfile.csv',sep=";",encoding='latin-1')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['val1','val2'])


# Connect to SQL Server

server = 'azure.....'
database = 'xxxx'
username = 'xxxx'
password = 'xxxx'
driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' + server + ';PORT=9999;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
cursor = conn.cursor()



# Insert DataFrame to Table
# Insert DataFrame to Table
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Database.dbo.mytable(val1,val2)
                VALUES (?,?)
                ''',
                   row.val1,
                   row.val2,
                   )
conn.commit()´´´
```

Comment: "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" is rather old. Can you try upgrading to "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" and see if that helps?

Comment: I`ve tried..without success.
Parameter 4 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float

Comment: Consider installing SQLAlchemy, creating an `engine` that points to the SQL Server instance and specifies `fast_executemany=True`, and then use pandas' `to_sql` method.